# Evaluating functors inside a functor in Prolog

Tags: prolog, functor

I follow the book *Problem solving with Prolog* by John Stobo. I've studied the Chapter 1 (*Programming with Facts*) and Chapter 2 (*Programming with Rules*) Now I am at Chapter 3: R*ecursion in Rules* and I'm practicing the program given in the Section 3.1. I've elobarated the program a bit (without changing the main structure) and added my own functor (or function or rule ?) named `is_rank_lower/2` but it doesn't work as expected.

When I enter (or ask Prolog)

is_rank_lower(ryan, jondoe).

the output is

false.

the expected output: true.

Because ryan is a private and jondoe is a corporal and private is lower in rank than corporal.

The explanations are in the code.

**Question #1**: How to make my own functor is_lower_rank work as expected?

**Question #2**: This question might be related to the book because when I write down the program exactly as it is, it works slightly wrongly and that might be causing my own functor to function wrongly, too. Just a guess.

When I enter:

lower_rank(private, corporal).

Prolog returns with `true` and waits at it, I have to put a dot after the `true` and click enter only then does it return to the `?-` prompt.

The expected output is:

return with `true.` then return to the `?-` prompt

The author seems to talk about this problem.  In page 57 he writes "lower_rank would not terminae if the goal ought to fail" I've applied all the instructions but the functor still doesn't work. How to make it work?

My prolog version **swi-prolog 7.2.0**

```
% John Stobo, problem solving with Prolog, March.1989

% FACTS:
next_degree(private, corporal). 
next_degree(corporal, sergeant).
next_degree(sergeant, lieutenant).
next_degree(lieutenant, captain).
next_degree(captain, major).
next_degree(major, "lieutenant colonel").
next_degree("lieutenant colonel", colonel).
next_degree(colonel, "brigadier general").
next_degree("brigadier general", "major general").
next_degree("major general","lieutenant general").
next_degree("lieutenant general", general).

soldier(ryan, private).
soldier(jondoe, corporal).
sooldier(smartson, captain).

% RULES:
lower_rank(R1, R2) :-
    next_degree(R1, R2).
 
lower_rank(R1, R2) :- % this works but if  
    next_degree(R1, R3), % the result is "true"
    lower_rank(R3, R2). % it doesn't end properly
% only if  the user types a dot, it ends properly

is_rank_lower(A1,A2) :-
    lower_rank(soldier(A1,X), soldier(A2,X)).
% doesn't work because the functors are inserted as
% 'soldier(ryan, _G1471), soldier(jondoe, _G1471))
% not as private, corporal, i.e. they are not evaluated
```

Comment: Just want to mention: if your issue is with unwanted choicepoints, rather than actual logical errors, then my advice is: simply don't worry about them. As you become more familiar with Prolog, you'll learn how to handle them (using e.g. once/1) .

Comment: @brebs thank you for the comment. Actually I don't plan to use Prolog for a long time. I 'm interested in it mainly out of curiosity.

Comment: @GuyCoder yep I was mixing strings with atoms because the SWI didn't complain when I entered those strings with the intention to be used as variable or better say, atoms.

Comment: @GuyCoder I've just tried compare(Oder, 'a b', "a b"). and it returned with `Oder = (>).` I think it give the priority rank according to some criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That next_degree/2 seems like a bizarre method - is the book suggesting it as sensible, or as an example of what not to do?

There are decent books at https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/useful-prolog-references/1089

This works:

```
% First argument is an atom, hence single quotes in swi-prolog
rank_order(private, 1).
rank_order(corporal, 2).
rank_order(sergeant, 3).
rank_order(lieutenant, 4).
rank_order(captain, 5).
rank_order(major, 6).
rank_order('lieutenant colonel', 7).
rank_order(colonel, 8).
rank_order('brigadier general', 9).
rank_order('major general', 10).
rank_order('lieutenant general', 11).

soldier(ryan, private).
soldier(jondoe, corporal).
% Not mis-spelled as "sooldier"
soldier(smartson, captain).

rank_lower(RankLower, RankUpper) :-
    rank_order(RankLower, RankLowerOrder),
    rank_order(RankUpper, RankUpperOrder),
    RankLowerOrder < RankUpperOrder.

soldier_rank_lower(SoldierLower, SoldierUpper) :-
    soldier(SoldierLower, RankLower),
    soldier(SoldierUpper, RankUpper),
    rank_lower(RankLower, RankUpper).
```

Results in swi-prolog:

```
?- rank_lower(private, corporal).
true.

?- soldier_rank_lower(ryan, jondoe).
true.

?- soldier_rank_lower(L, U).
L = ryan,
U = jondoe ;
L = ryan,
U = smartson ;
L = jondoe,
U = smartson ;
false.
```

2nd attempt:

```
rank_next(private, corporal).
rank_next(corporal, sergeant).
rank_next(sergeant, lieutenant).
rank_next(lieutenant, captain).
rank_next(captain, major).
rank_next(major, 'lieutenant colonel').
rank_next('lieutenant colonel', colonel).
rank_next(colonel, 'brigadier general').
rank_next('brigadier general', 'major general').
rank_next('major general', 'lieutenant general').
rank_next('lieutenant general', general).

soldier(ryan, private).
soldier(jondoe, corporal).
soldier(smartson, captain).

rank_lower(RankLower, RankUpper) :-
    rank_next(RankLower, RankLower1),
    % Increase lower to eventually meet with upper
    (   RankLower1 = RankUpper ;
        rank_lower(RankLower1, RankUpper)
    ).

soldier_rank_lower(SoldierLower, SoldierUpper) :-
    soldier(SoldierLower, RankLower),
    soldier(SoldierUpper, RankUpper),
    % Won't have multiple answers
    once(rank_lower(RankLower, RankUpper)).
```

This makes the following deterministic:

```
?- soldier_rank_lower(ryan, jondoe).
true.
```

... whilst keeping the generality of rank_lower/2, i.e.:

```
?- findall(L-U, rank_lower(L, U), Pairs), length(Pairs, Len).
Pairs = [private-corporal,private-sergeant,private-lieutenant, ...
Len = 66.
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, it only answers / corrects the second question: The double quotes might really be the reason SWI prompt not returning properly. When I replaced all double quotes with single quotes, SWI prompt started to return properly. I've corrected the typo at the `soldier` too. Now the Question #2 is asnwered but the main question is not. I'd like to make the functor `is_lower_rank` work without rewriting the whole code i.e. the main body of code should stay as it is in the book. Soon I'll add the question a bounty of 250 to get this message through.

Comment: Extended answer, should be acceptable now.